# Is there a good way to keep cats/animals from scratching on a door?

Tags: noise-reduction, pet-proofing

My girlfriend doesn't like sleeping with my two cats in the room at night, so I've started keeping the door to my bedroom closed.  Unfortunately, however, they meow and scratch **all night long**.

Is there some way to keep them from scratching, or to damper down the noise so we can sleep soundly?

I have hardwood floors, and I'm sure this doesn't help with the acoustic amplification of the sound.

Comment: I believe the scratching is them trying to get in, not just natural cat scratching behavior.

Comment: I agree with Jason.  You've separated them from their herd/pack and their favorite night-time napping place.  This isn't like trying to get them to stop clawing the furniture.

Comment: I had the same problem with my cat.  She now sleeps on my head.

Comment: Question for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pets ?

Comment: I've been a cat owner now for 2 years? Their very much habit animals. If something changes, it takes them time to adjust (mine anyways). Let it go. in a few days, they'll stop. Or wake up at 2am and start playing with their toys. Either way, your sure as hell not gonna stop them.

Comment: As a temporary measure you could tape tinfoil to the wall/door. That has worked for me though of course it looks crummy.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on a pet-focused website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend at work told me this one:

Buy a roll or two of clear double-sided tape and put it on the bottom of the door and the bottom of the door frame.

When the cats scratch at it, their paws get stuck/sticky (they don't like this at all) and they'll soon learn not to scratch at the door.

Answer (score 3):

you can use an automated air jet/[spray](http://www.petsmart.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2751025) that activates when the cat comes close to the door

(just a link I found wile googling "cat repellent door" no affiliation)